# Where is UserData script placed in a Windows EC2 instance?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is the UserData part stored anywhere on a Windows EC2 machine? I need to examine it to see that input variables are correct.

On Ubuntu, it's supposed to be stored at `/var/lib/cloud/instances/[instance-id]/user-data.txt` according to [this link](http://blog.hownowstephen.com/post/45268048932/where-is-ec2-user-data-stored).

The user data section in CloudFormation looks like this:

```
"UserData"         : {
    "Fn::Base64" : {
        "Fn::Join" : [
            "",
            [
                "<script>\n",
                "seedtool.exe ", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "DatabaseCluster" , "Endpoint.Address" ] }, "\n",
                "</script>\n"
            ]
        ]
    }
},
```

I need to see the user-data.txt so I can see what `{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "DatabaseCluster" , "Endpoint.Address" ] }` resolves to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User Data can be fetched from instance metadata, e.g. with `Invoke-RestMethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data`, for more details see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-user-data-retrieval

Comment: Yes, 169.254.169.254 IP is used both for linux and windows on all instances in AWS (and also in Azure). See e.g. here for more details http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: @sashoalm see also [What's Special About the 169.254.169.254 IP Address for AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42315582/1695906)

Comment: Running this in March 2023 and got a 404

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking for the actual location of the userdata script, it should be in:

`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\InvokeUserData\UserScript.ps1`

Note that files in this location (`...\AppData\Local\Temp\`) may be removed by cleanup processes or tools during the instance's lifetime.