# How to get account id and region dynamically while creating cloudwatch alarm via API

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-regions

I am making AutoRecovery alarm via API and i want to make my code work in any system by just calling the python script. but as every one has unique AWS account id and region can also be different, so i want to fetch account id and region dynamically.
get-caller-identity is used for account id. but i ain't able to get how to use this function basically!

Comment: *"make my code work in any system"* What does this mean?  Does the script create this alarm for the instance where it is running?

Comment: yes, thats what i mean!. and yes script is creating the alarm of what account id and region it has been hardcoded in script. i want it to be dynamic @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 0):

To identify these attributes of a particular EC2 instance from code running on the EC2 instance itself, use the [Instance Identity Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html).

Use any HTTP client utility to fetch this URL:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
```

You can test this from the command line with `curl`.

This returns a JSON document containing -- among other things -- `instanceId`, `accountId`, and `region` for the instance.

The IP address `169.254.169.254` is always the same for every instance in every region.  See also [What's special about 169.254.169.254 IP address for AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42315582/1695906)

While STS `GetCallerIdentity` can be used to identify certain attributes of the credentials currently in use, it should not be necessary.