# who provide service for instance meta-data access on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata

we can retrieve info via instance meta-data by cli or api, just like this:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

from [What's special about 169.254.169.254 IP address for AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314029/whats-special-about-169-254-169-254-ip-address-for-aws) we know that 169.254.169.254 is reserved IP and directly-connected.

I want to know who provide the service for retrieve meta-data? I found no service in EC2 instance by check ports and service.

I guess AWS implement this IP directly-connect,when instance receive this request,it will send another request with instance Id to some midware in aws(VPC or region), and midware search it in kv store and give a response.

who provide this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data provided on `169.254.169.254` is provided by the Amazon EC2 service at the *hypervisor* layer.

The information is only accessible from within the instance itself. The data is returned directly by the hypervisor and does not travel across the network.

As with much of AWS, there is no need to know the inner-workings of how a service is implemented. Rather, you can simply rely on the Amazon EC2 service making this information available to the instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it help me solve my doubt. And I found other cloud provider using different IP ranges.