# Expiration time of AWS EC2 instance profile credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

The official AWS documentation states that instance profile credentials ["are temporary and would eventually expire"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html), and I was wondering how often they expire.

I'am asking because I have applications using an `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` as credential provider, which by default does not refresh credentials, running for days without problems.

Comment: On the page you referenced, *"When you use this approach... Although these credentials are temporary and would eventually expire,  `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` periodically refreshes them for you so that the obtained credentials continue to allow access to AWS."*  This implies that it **does** refresh them.

Comment: `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/role_name` (where `role_name` is the actual name of the instance role) will show you the expiration time of the instance's current set of temporary credentials (as well as the actual credentials).  It's never more than a few hours, but I am not certain whether the max lifetime is officially documented.  169.254.169.254 is a [special internal address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42314029/1695906) providing a different response to each instance.  It's handled by the hypervisor.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for your second comment, I think it should be the answer. Regarding your first comment, it actually depends, if the provider is created with the default no-args constructor, or with the getInstance() method, it does not refresh them.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I checked the code, and my previous comment about refreshing is wrong: it actually starts refreshing credentials anyway when you call getCredentials().

Comment: @dipanda Your comment makes it sound like calling getCredentials() will always refresh credentials. I think it would only do so if the current cached credentials are expired or close to expiration.

Answer (score 5):

We have noticed from logging that the temporary credentials issued against an attached role last approximately 6 hours.

Does anyone know the mechanism of how they are refreshed, supposedly 15 minutes before they expire?  Is the SSM service monitoring the expiration and asking for new credentials?

We are currently chasing down what appears to be an issue with the credentials not being refreshed after the EC2 instance has no activity on the overnight.  Trying to determine whether app pool idle timeout or recycle interval is playing a hand.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials

`We make new credentials available at least five minutes before the expiration of the old credentials.`