# Boto3 Pre-Sign Upload URL takes very long to generate

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, gunicorn

I have a Python application that needs to generate many Pre-Sign Upload URLs for a single bucket on our AWS cloud.

I noticed a strange behavior - it seems that every so often generating the URL would take around 5 seconds instead of the nano seconds it usually takes. I vaguely remember that generating a URL is a local operation and I couldn't find any documentation on this.

I'm running a `Falcon` app over `Gunicorn` with `boto3~=1.20.54`. The Gunicorn is configured with multiple sync workers and same number of threads.

It should be noted that this is a rare occurrence but it is very random and I can't explain it. I did find some explanations that the `boto3` client is somewhat lazy in that it loads meta data on the `S3` bucket on the [first operation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html) (see Warning section). I added a `noop` call to `list_buckets` as the first thing when the app loads but it didn't affect the behavior.

Any help will be apprecicated.

Comment: How are you providing credentials to your S3 client? Are you running in an environment with an assumed role? Can you correlate the times when generating the URL takes a long time to the existence of `AssumeRole` events in CloudTrail?

Comment: You are correct -- creating a pre-signed URL is a local operation. It is simply creating a hash on the object details and the Secret Access Key. It does not even need to retrieve information about the bucket.

Comment: @kdgregory I didn't consider this option. My environment uses roles but the I use a containerised environment and if this is the case I would expect only the first operation to be slow but what I'm seeing that it's quite random.

Comment: Can you show the affected code? How do know that the culprit is the pre-sign operation and not something else?

Comment: The reason I suggested roles is that, while signing a URL is indeed a local operation, you need to have credentials in order to sign it. When using a instance/execution roles, that means that at some point the system needs to retrieve new credentials, which is an external operation. How that happens (eg, on background thread, system service, ...) depends on platform; I don't know the details for any of them, just that it has to happen.

Comment: The only other option is that there's something in your Python code that's blocking the entire interpreter (ie, "when in doubt, blame the GIL"). However that shouldn't _just_ impact signing URLs (but maybe that's where you see the issue, and it's happening at other times). I might also look at Python garbage collection: I don't know the details of how it works (other than using reference counting rather than tracing), but would expect an occasional compact phase if you're creating a lot of short-lived objects.

Comment: @kdgregory I believe you're correct. I've enabled boto3's debug logs and I see the refresh code running and taking a long time to execute. This is also backed by the fact that I noticed that the long requests happens on roughly strict intervals.

Comment: This question also seems to be of similar mindset - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609051/expiration-time-of-aws-ec2-instance-profile-credentials