# How do I determine whether my application is running in Amazon EC2 *without* network calls?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have a tool I'm writing that's meant to access S3 either with implicit IAM role credentials (when running in S3) or with explicit credentials in the environment or config files (when running outside S3).

The default behavior of the AWS SDK (I'm using the Go version, but I assume  the other SDKs are similar) is to prefer environment credentials, then config credentials, then fall back to IAM role credentials, and only fail if the IAM role credentials can't be retrieved. Unfortunately, this requires a network call that can take anywhere up to 20 seconds to time out.

I'd like to **quickly** determine whether I'm running in EC2, so I know whether it's worth even making that call. Unfortunately, the AWS APIs that look like they should provide that information (e.g. [EC2Metadata.Available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/ec2metadata/#EC2Metadata.Available)) make that same network call and suffer from the same timeout issue.

At the moment the only thing I can think of is to shell out and check whether `uname -a` includes `"amzn"`.

This seems less than ideal.

Is there a good way to check for an EC2 environment without making any network calls?

Comment: Does your code read a config file at startup?  Store The location (EC2 vs. other) there.

Comment: It doesn't. The config file I mentioned in the question is the AWS config file, which is read implicitly by the AWS SDK.

Comment: *"Unfortunately, this requires a network call that can take anywhere up to 20 seconds to time out."*  Explicitly set a shorter timeout?  If you're in EC2, [the instance metadata service at 169.254.169.254:80](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42314029/1695906) responds in milliseconds.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Interesting idea. I'll have to see if the AWS API supports configuring that.

Comment: `aws-cli` seems to automatically use a very short timeout.  I can't say about Go or any of the other SDKs but the source code should tell the story.  I discovered this behavior by accident while developing a service that emulated instance metadata (for local development) and ran on an old Raspberry Pi.  The Pi's dinky CPU would bog down a bit while processing part of the request, and before the response came back, the cli would give up and say no credentials could be found.

Answer (score 0):

You could set environment variables for your tool that tells your application where it is running.

Comment: If I could count on the users of the tool to set environment variables, I could also count on them to configure their credentials properly. :\

Comment: then why not just make explicit credentials the default (which will work everywhere), and have an optional IAM option that has to be set explicitly?