# Is 169.254.169.254 only used by AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address

I'm planning to make a script for package installation, mainly targeted for EC2 Instances.

What I'm planning to do is `amazon-linux-extras`, and `curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4` and  `curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4` if ec2, else `yum add-repo`.

However, what I'm concerned is this script being run by non-ec2 instances as I'm planning to share this script with the public, and the main concern is some machines that aren't EC2 instances having access to `169.254.169.254`.

I googled that IP address but couldn't find another use case other than AWS. Is it okay to assume `curl 169.254.169.254` returning something means they're EC2 instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's special about 169.254.169.254 IP address for AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42314029/1695906).

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: It is also used by the Google Compute Engine. See: [Internal DNS  |  Compute Engine Documentation  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you, now I think of it I don’t know why I couldn’t remember there is another cloud platform other than AWS. Silly me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little late to answer this question but just in case anyone else comes across this question as well; not only AWS uses `169.254.169.254`. Other cloud services that also use `169.254.169.254` for accessing their instance metadata includes Digital Ocean, Azure, OpenStack/RackSpace, HP Helion. This is as far as I know of as of today.