# AWS: instance metadata for iam is not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up elasticsearch s3 snapshots on my ec2 instances. And it fails with following error:

```
nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[sdk_client_exception: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
```

If I query the metadata server from that ec2 instance, it responses the following:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
events/
hostname
identity-credentials/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
services/
```

So there is no **iam** section.

How to make iam section available for querying from ec2 instance ?

Comment: I believe it only shows up if you have an IAM role attached to your EC2 instance. Please check this after attaching an IAM role to the EC2 instance with ability to put objects in S3 bucket.

Comment: When I hit the API from power-shell `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` we are getting `404 not found` but on Chrome browser it's working.

Comment: Should be "trying to set up" not "trying to setup".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following meta-data URI will return something if you have the role attached to the given ec2 instance:

`http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/`

so it looks like you don't have an IAM role attached. Please verify.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday. My automation created a instance profile but it does not have assume role.

```
{
    "InstanceProfile": {
        "Path": "/",
        "InstanceProfileName": "example_instance_profile",
        "InstanceProfileId": "<id>",
        "Arn": "<arn>",
        "CreateDate": "«date_time>",
        "Roles": []
    }
}
```

I deleted this instance profile and created again with automation.

```
{
    "InstanceProfile": {
        "Path": "/",
        "InstanceProfileName": "<profile_name>",
        "InstanceProfileId": "<profile_id>",
        "Arn": "<arn>",
        "CreateDate": "«date_time>",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Path": "/",
                "RoleName": "<role_name>",
                "RoleId": "<role_id>",
                "Arn": "<arn>",
                "CreateDate": "<date>",
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "<date>",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Sid": "",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```